# Example of no where differentiable function defined on non compact domain

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any continuous, no where differentiable function which has been defined on a domain such that it is not compact?
That is does there exists $f:A\to R$ which is no where differentiable such that $A$ is not compact??

Comment: Won't any non-differentiable function on $\mathbb R$ suffice?  Such as any discontinuous solution of the Cauchy functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$? Or Brownian motion?  Or  a periodic extension of your favorite nowhere differentiable function on $[0,1)$?

Comment: Sir is it continuous all over R??I don't think so!!!

Comment: 1.  What does "it" refer to in your comment.  2.  What does "continuous all over R" have to do with the problem you posed?

Comment: The question didn't put any requirement on that the function has to be continuous. You should try to take your time to formulate questions so that such misunderstandings occurs. Think of it: as soon as you post your question people may start spending their time on answering your question and if they then answer a question that don't properly convey your intentions their time will be wasted.

Comment: Sir the question of differentiability comes when it is assmed that the function is continuous.In case of discontinuous functions I thought they won't hold any good property.So I assumed that the reader will leave the case of discontinuous functions.If this was my fault I am really sorry for it

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, one example is the Dirichlet function

$$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{c c} 1 & if \ x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & else \end{array} \right. $$

The Weierstrass function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is even continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ but nowhere differentiable. There are of course many other examples, but $\mathbb{R}$ is a simple non-compact space.

Comment: Now is it possible to have an approximation of the no where differentiable but everywhere continuous function to a function which is differentiable at atleast countably many points